# cant get the output for the day using onchange

Tags: html

> I do it by my own idea how to get the leap year for the month of February with the condition of the month and year that output the date range.

---

here's my HTML code...

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Expect to Loan:</td>
    <td colspan="1">
    <select name="month" onchange="getday();">
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>            
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>

</select>

<select name="day" id="day" style="margin-left:5px;">
<option value="">Day</option>


</select>


<select name="year" id="year" style="margin-left:5px;">
<option value="0">Year</option>

<script type="text/javascript">

var date = new Date();
var yr = date.getFullYear('yyyy');

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

document.write("<option value='" + yr + "'>" + yr + "    </option>");
            yr = yr + 1;
            }

        </script>


    </select>


    </td>
</tr>
```

My Javascript code for day every changes in month and year

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getday(){
        var month = document.forms['calcu']['month'].value;

        alert('month change');

        if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){

        for (var = 1; i <= 31; i++) {

            alert('date end on 31');
            document.write("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");

            }
    }

    else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month = 9 || month == 9 || month == 11){
        for (var = 1; i <= 30; i++) {

            alert('date end on 30');

            document.write("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");

            }
    }

        </script>
```

> what DOM Event should I use to get my output on date.
>   Please help me with my codes.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var date = new Date();
    var yr = date.getFullYear('yyyy');

   for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    document.write("<option value='" + yr + "'>" + yr + "</option>");
    yr = yr + 1;
    }

 </script>
            

 <script type="text/javascript">

   function getday(){
   var month = document.forms['calcu']['month'].value;
   
   //alert('month change');

   if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){

   for (var = 1; i <= 31; i++) {

   // alert('date end on 31');
    document.write("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");

    }
  }

  else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 9 || month == 11){
   for (var = 1; i <= 30; i++) {

    //alert('date end on 30');

    document.write("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");

    }
  }

   </script>
```

```html
<select name="month" onchange="getday();">
  <option value="0">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>   
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>

  </select>

  <select name="day" id="day" style="margin-left:5px;">
   
   <option value="">Day</option>


  </select>


  <select name="year" id="year" style="margin-left:5px;">
   
   <option value="0">Year</option>
   
  </select>
```

Comment: Got it already and I dont know know how is it.

Comment: Can I ask now how to write inline html codes using javascript. the output was change all the code in code inside the <html> Tag </html>